# ParticlesJS background больше чем в один экран

Tags: javascript, canvas

Собственно сабж.

Всё отлично с любой высотой `<=` высоте экрана

```js
window.onload = function() {
  Particles.init({
    selector: '.background'
  });
};
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.background {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;  
 left: 0;
  height: 1200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.2.3/particles.min.js"></script>
<body> 
<canvas class="background"></canvas>
</body>
```

Но когда контента на странице становится больше чем на один экран, частицы ниже не отрисовываются.
Существует ли в природе способ заполнить частицами весь background любой высоты?

Comment: Вы для `.background` явно указываете высоту в `1200px`. Соответственно, вам надо вычислить нужную вам высоту, затем задать для `.background` эту высоту, потом инициализировать `Particles`.

Comment: Видимо в спешке оставил явно заданную высоту. Так как страница без контента, хотел видеть как ведут себя particles при большой высоте `.background`

Comment: Я еще совсем зелёный, поэтому уточняю - так чтобы частицы заполняли весь `background` нужно копать в сторону js? Или проблему можно решить средствами сss?

Comment: Сразу так ответить сложно. Если `background` превышает высоту окна, то скорее всего надо использовать `js` для вычисления высоты. Приведите пример кода, где бы высота была больше окна браузера.